# How to sort DataSet in c#

Tags: c#

Do you know how to sort DataSet with quick sort or merge sort in windows form?

```cs
DataView dv = new DataView(ds.Tables[0]);

//apply our row filter. get only records with a lastname of 'Callahan'
dv.RowFilter = "Name = 'Brown'";

//close our connection
sqlConnection.Close();

//return our dataview
return dv;
```

That can't help me.
Must be sorted by grade.

Comment: I don't write C# at all, but quick [Google](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=sort+dataview+c%23) gave me a link to the documemtation on [DataView.Sort Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataview.sort?view=net-5.0). What was wrong with that?

Comment: since you've tagged this sql-server: If you don't want to work with a view and don't want to clone the underlying datatable then why not just ORDER BY field_name DESC in your sql query?

Comment: It would also, probably, be quicker to filter the data in the RDBMS if you have the relevant indexes.